# Calling up an arbitrary dictation app from within a keyboard app (Swype)

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition, swype

I've been using the Swype/Dragon keyboard for years, because I found its swipe-typing function to work best, and the voice dictation was also the best for the languages I needed.

Despite the app's [discontinuation](https://www.xda-developers.com/swype-keyboard-android-dragon-dictation-discontinued/), the keyboard still works fine, in fact better than others I've tried, such as GBoard or Microsoft SwiftKey. However, the Dragon voice dictation server is down, so one can no longer use voice typing from within the Swype keyboard.

Is there any way to keep Swype as a default keyboard but call up some other dictation component/app, such as Google Voice Typing, upon pressing the microphone key in Swype (below)?
[image]

Comment: Why not use GBoard  for both swipe typing and speech recognition?  That's what I do